# How to extract cyclic object contain html element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I tried to use https://github.com/artsy/day-schedule-selector to build a time slot based scheduler, but it returns an object like this
[image]

It can't be stringified, parse, or anything else.
I've tried this method

```
 Object.entries(selected).forEach(entry => {
        const [key, value] = entry;
        console.log(value);
    });
```

and the return was this
[image]
again, I cannot access it through deserialize, stringify, to string or else. When I stringify it and return json data like this : `{"jQuery111208320953175692328":23}`

I need to extract data-time for each of it

Comment: Please paste the json object as text in your question so that we may try   solutions on it.

Comment: I know it strange, I cannot use right click then copy object, it produce object like this
`{
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "length": 2,
  "prevObject": {
    "0": {},
    "1": {},
    "length": 24,
    "prevObject": {
      "0": {},
      "context": {},
      "length": 1
    },
    "context": {},
    "selector": ".time-slot[data-day=\"5\"]"
  },
  "context": {}
}`

that's why I use image

Comment: if you are trying to get the selected cells, try this 

`var selected = $("#schedule-selector").data('artsy.dayScheduleSelector').serialize()`

serialize() returns an object containing the selections of each day

Comment: Thanks, serialize() help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I queried data-selected items within the scheduler and tried to extract day and time. I hope this is useful to you.

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('[data-selected]'));
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('[data-selected]');
for (i = 0; i < nodelist.length; i++) 
{
    console.log(" day : " +nodelist[i].dataset.day +" time :"     +nodelist[i].dataset.time );
}
```

here is an example output after selecting random days on the calendar:

```
day : 0 time :09:30 
day : 2 time :09:30 
day : 0 time :10:00 
day : 2 time :10:00 
day : 0 time :10:30 
day : 2 time :10:30 
day : 4 time :11:00 
day : 4 time :11:30 
day : 6 time :11:30 
day : 4 time :12:00 
day : 6 time :12:00 
day : 6 time :12:30 
day : 0 time :13:00 
day : 0 time :13:30 
day : 3 time :13:30 
day : 3 time :14:00
```

Comment: Awesome, now I can embed it with 
`$("#day-schedule").on('selected.artsy.dayScheduleSelector', function() {}`

And call ajax request using it to update immediately the database

Many thanks to you @AntiqTech